# Storing structure members in human readable format

Tags: c++, serialization, struct

I have a strange requirement to implement. Below structure needs to be stored in hard disk in human readable format.
(It is required so that i can modify values and avoid generating/capturing from real time environment)
And the same structure needs to be read back into the C++ code.

```
struct trailerSense_NonVolatileLearnData
{
    uint32_t version;
    wheelBaseEstimation wheelbaseState; //Its a structure
    nonVolatileData feature[trailerSense_NUM_FEATURES]; //Its a structure
    float32_t featureDistanceMinX;
    uint16_t numFeaturesStored;
};
```

is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I would recommend storing it as XML, JSON or something similar. That's human readable, and also easy to save/load for the computer.

Comment: Yes, using very standard ones. What have you tried that failed?

Comment: [How exactly do I read/write simple types in human-readable (“text”) format?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization#serialize-text-format)

Comment: While it is a good idea to use some standard format, in very easy examples it is also ok to just print the members space seperated in one line. If this example is "very easy" of course depends on the definition of the two member structs.